# csv unique values without considering a column

Tags: python, csv

I've a csv as :

```
name1, age1, location1, phone1
name1, age1, location2, phone1
name1, age1, location3, phone1
name2, age2, location4, phone2
```

In the above data, the three rows are almost the same with only the location being different. I just want a single row from the three similar rows(anyone would work). So my final output would be like:

```
name1, age1, location1, phone1
name2, age2, location4, phone2
```

or

```
name1, age1, location2, phone1
name2, age2, location4, phone2
```

or

```
name1, age1, location3, phone1
name2, age2, location4, phone2
```

Is there any way we could do it in `python`. Any suggestion would be highly useful.

Comment: So based on what element you detect that the rows are unique?`name1` or `age1` or `phone1`?

Comment: so you want to pick any one row that matches a unique phone #?  as in, any of one of the 3 phone1 rows?  and any one of the 1 phone2 rows?

Comment: The first three rows are almost similar, i want only one out of them.

Comment: got it.  started on an answer, but then realized Daniel had been way ahead of all of us on this one ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary with the unique fields as key:

```
data = {}
for name, age, location, phone in csv_data:
    data[name, age] = (name, age, location, phone)
```

so you would keep always the last entry.